convert video to audio - ffmpeg
I'm trying to convert video to audio using ffmpeg in flutter based application but command is not working.
Is there something wrong with the command?
  void convert(File pickedVideo) async {
    Directory applicationDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final outputPath = '${applicationDocDirectory.path}/output-audio-${const Uuid().v1()}.mp3';

    final session = await FFmpegKit.execute('-i ${pickedVideo.path} -vn -acodec mp3 $outputPath');

    final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

    print(ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)); // return false
  }


You can try splitting the arguments for session.
final session = await FFmpegKit.execute(['-i', pickedVideo.path, '-vn', '-acodec', 'mp3', outputPath]);

Your code will look something like this
void convert(File pickedVideo) async {
 Directory applicationDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

 final outputPath = '${applicationDocDirectory.path}/output-audio-${const Uuid().v1()}.mp3';

 final session = await FFmpegKit.execute(['-i', pickedVideo.path, '-vn', '-acodec', 'mp3', outputPath]);

 final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

 print(ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)); // return false
}


just tested it! Didn't work :( still printing false
